# How to sort a table based on a particular word if there are multiple words in that cell in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

If a table cell contains multiple words, for e.g. "Jobs, Steve (Abc-04-PQA, INC)", how to sort the table based on first name (Steve) or last name (Job) in Java?

Comment: Write Person class and his comparator class for comparison.

Comment: Show of what you have tried and please be more specific about where you come in doubt. Also, what more precisely do you mean by table? Database table, array, JTable, …?

Comment: Hows is this a selenium/webdriver question btw?

Answer (score 0):

Only if the format of the table cells are strictly followed can you use a delimiter to figure out how to sort based on first name. If you use the ", " as the delimiter you can use what follows as the variable to sort with.